# Composer update results in "symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found."

Tags: symfony, composer-php

The error message is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found.
[snip]
```

The composer version is `d929a0813ae473272d151d9ebb2af7ebae451e48`, with the following bundles installed:

- antimattr/google-bundle             dev-master 934add2
- braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle       dev-master v1.3.1
- doctrine/common                     2.3.x-dev bb0aebb
- doctrine/data-fixtures              dev-master eef10f6
- doctrine/dbal                       2.3.x-dev fd45c6f
- doctrine/doctrine-bundle            v1.2.0-beta1
- doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle   dev-master 275540d
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master 99c0192
- doctrine/migrations                 dev-master e1f6efc
- doctrine/orm                        2.3.x-dev 304acf0
- friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle     dev-master 75d781e
- friendsofsymfony/rest               0.8.0
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle        dev-master c334e61
- friendsofsymfony/user-bundle        dev-master 993eebf
- gedmo/doctrine-extensions           dev-master 0697ecc
- hwi/oauth-bundle                    dev-master 461cdae
- jdorn/sql-formatter                 v1.2.0
- jms/aop-bundle                      1.0.0
- jms/cg                              1.0.0
- jms/di-extra-bundle                 1.3.0
- jms/metadata                        1.2.0-RC
- jms/parser-lib                      1.0.0
- jms/security-extra-bundle           1.4.0
- jms/serializer                      0.11.0
- jms/serializer-bundle               0.11.0
- jquery/jquery                       1.9.1
- kriswallsmith/assetic               dev-master df03baa
- kriswallsmith/buzz                  v0.7
- leafo/lessphp                       dev-master 54bb805
- monolog/monolog                     1.4.0
- ornicar/akismet-bundle              dev-master 008cb45
- phpcollection/phpcollection         0.2.0
- phpoption/phpoption                 1.1.0
- psr/log                             1.0.0
- sensio/distribution-bundle          v2.2.0
- sensio/framework-extra-bundle       v2.2.0
- sensio/generator-bundle             v2.2.0
- swiftmailer/swiftmailer             v4.3.0
- symfony/assetic-bundle              dev-master 6985b26
- symfony/monolog-bundle              v2.2.0
- symfony/swiftmailer-bundle          v2.2.0
- symfony/symfony                     v2.2.0
- twig/extensions                     dev-master 5c2d515
- twig/twig                           dev-master bc30d9b
- twitter/bootstrap                   v2.3.1

Googling for the error message mainly returns results containing the error message, but no solution, or pointer in the right direction...

It could be a coincidence, but this message started showing up *after* running a `composer self-update`

[edit]
My `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0":         {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias":         {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        },
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "package":             {
                "dist":                 {
                    "type": "file",
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
                },
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.9.1"
            },
            "type": "package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "antimattr/google-bundle": "dev-master",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "master-dev",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jquery/jquery": "1.9.*",
        "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
        "ornicar/akismet-bundle": "dev-master",
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.0,<=2.2-dev",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "2.3.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `composer.json`? Have you tried to manually empty the `vendor` folder before running the update?

Comment: I agree with @cheesemacfly, please post your composer.json contents and tell us the _exact_ version of Symfony you are using.

Comment: Updated my question with the contents of `composer.json`.  renamed `vendor` to `vendor.old` and ran composer update, unfortunately the error message remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you replace in your `composer.json`:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.0,<=2.2-dev"
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "*"
```

With (for example):

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "v2.2.0",
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.2.*@dev"
```

The 2 problems were:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.0,<=2.2-dev"
```

That requires:

```
symfony/translator: 2.0.7
```

But this one doesn't exist anymore...
And then

```
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "*"
```

because it needs:

```
symfony/framework-bundle: >=2.0,<2.2-dev
```

So your full `composer.json` will be:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0":         {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias":         {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        },
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "package":             {
                "dist":                 {
                    "type": "file",
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
                },
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.9.1"
            },
            "type": "package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",

        "antimattr/google-bundle": "dev-master",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "master-dev",
        "jquery/jquery": "1.9.*",
        "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
        "ornicar/akismet-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "2.3.*",

        "symfony/framework-bundle": "v2.2.0",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.2.*@dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
    }
}
```

I have split up with spaces the different requirements as follow:

1. The standard Symfony 2.2
2. The extra bundles in your project
3. The ones that were causing the issue